# Get multiple ElasticSearch indices in Bosun

Tags: elasticsearch, bosun

We have several different indices in ElasticSearch:

- myindex1.messages.ttl60-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}
- myindex2.messages.ttl60-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}
- myindex3.messages.ttl60-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}

All of them shares the same scheme and is used to log events.
Now I want to create ONE alert in BOSUN for all listed indices, but I don't want to write their names explicitly.

Can I have some kind of pattern matching for indices just like we have in Kibana: ***messages***?

I tried [esindices](https://bosun.org/expressions#elastic-index-functions) expression, but it requires literal names of indices.

Comment: Never considered this possibility. Might be able to make a new indexer function that combines existing indexers. For now I think you best bet would be to make three queries within an alert definition (i.e. an escount for each myindex# using the daily indexer) and them `merge(..)` the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just combine all the indices with a template into an alias on elastic side.